# Scala, writing abstract methods

Tags: scala, methods, abstract

I'm wondering if there is a way to write an abstract method for similar classes. I have several classes that have a "weight" value for example and I wont to apply this method to a list of different classes. Is there a way this can be done?

```
def addPersons (a: List[Person], b:List[Person], bc:List[Person]): Int =
    if (a.isEmpty) 0
    else if (b.isEmpty) addPersons (a.tail, bc, List[Person]())
    else if (a.head == b.head) a.head.weight + addPersons(a.tail, bc ++ b, List[Person]())
    else addPersons(a, b.tail, b.head :: bc)
```

Comment: You can create a trait with the method in it and then extend each of these classes with that trait.

Comment: so if I write the method with the trait instead I can pass it any class that is extended from that trait?

Comment: Yes. Then each object of these classes will have that function.